# How can I rsync to all remote connected host?

Tags: ssh, rsync

I'm using following command to transfer file using `rsync` to only one connected host:

```
rsync -az -e ssh /path/to/source 192.168.8.8:/path/to/destination
```

This is the case of static ip addesss. But in other case there are more than one system connected using DHCP.

I've tried:

```
rsync -az -e ssh /path/to/source 192.168.8.*:/path/to/destination
```

But it shows an error

```
ssh: could not resolve the hostname 192.168.8.*: Name or service not known
```

Comment: `rysnc` has to know where to send it; so you have to find the address to send it to, before you issue the command. if one address is static, have the dynamic addresses periodically send messages reporting their addresses to the static address; then lookup the address from the static machine.  (script this & use whatever encryption is appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards and the simple regex (e.g. `ls /usr/bin/x[bc]*`) only work on the local filesystem.

Wildcards cannot know, which remote host you want copy the folders to. You need a loop for that:

```
for i in $(seq 8 18); do; \
   rsync -az -e ssh /path/to/source 192.168.8.$i:/path/to/destination; \
done
```

This will copy the `source` to all host from 192.168.8.8 to 192.168.8.18.

Comment: Yes I'd thought the same to do. I've made a script as per requirement. Just wanted to know if it works with wildcards or not with a single command.

Comment: Well, no... wildcards and also the simple regex only work on the local filesystem

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` can only copy to one destination at a time, like `ssh` can only connect to one destination per invocation.

However, you may want to have a look at the package [pssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) (for Parallel SSH), which also provides parallel rsync:

```
- Parallel rsync (parallel-rsync, upstream calls it prsync), efficiently
  copies files to multiple hosts in parallel
```